# Unit test a void method with Mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I want to test a void method with Mock.

```
 public class ConsoleTargetBuilder : ITargetBuilder
{
    private const string CONSOLE_WITH_STACK_TRACE = "consoleWithStackTrace";
    private const string CONSOLE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE = "consoleWithoutStackTrace";
    private LoggerModel _loggerModel;
    private LoggingConfiguration _nLogLoggingConfiguration;

    public ConsoleTargetBuilder(LoggerModel loggerModel, LoggingConfiguration nLogLoggingConfiguration)
    {
        _loggerModel = loggerModel;
        _nLogLoggingConfiguration = nLogLoggingConfiguration;
    }

    public void AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()
    {
        var consoleTargetWithStackTrace = new ConsoleTarget();
        consoleTargetWithStackTrace.Name = CONSOLE_WITH_STACK_TRACE;
        consoleTargetWithStackTrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout + "|${stacktrace}";
        _nLogLoggingConfiguration.AddTarget(CONSOLE_WITH_STACK_TRACE, consoleTargetWithStackTrace);

        var consoleTargetWithoutStackTrace = new ConsoleTarget();
        consoleTargetWithoutStackTrace.Name = CONSOLE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE;
        consoleTargetWithoutStackTrace.Layout = _loggerModel.layout;
        _nLogLoggingConfiguration.AddTarget(CONSOLE_WITHOUT_STACK_TRACE, consoleTargetWithoutStackTrace);
    }
```

The thing is I am not sure how to test it. I have my primary code.

```
public class ConsoleTargetBuilderUnitTests
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> ConsoleTargetBuilderTestData
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                 new object[]
                {
                    new LoggerModel(),
                    new LoggingConfiguration(),
                    2
                }
            };
        }
    }
    [Theory]
    [MemberData("ConsoleTargetBuilderTestData")]
    public void ConsoleTargetBuilder_Should_Add_A_Console_Target(LoggerModel loggerModel, LoggingConfiguration nLogLoggingConfiguration, int expectedConsoleTargetCount)
    {
        // ARRANGE
        var targetBuilderMock = new Mock<ITargetBuilder>();
        targetBuilderMock.Setup(x => x.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()).Verifiable();
        // ACT
        var consoleTargetBuilder = new ConsoleTargetBuilder(loggerModel, nLogLoggingConfiguration);
        // ASSERT
        Assert.Equal(expectedConsoleTargetCount, nLogLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets.Count);
    }
```

Please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to inject the ConsoleTarget class into the Method. Then you can setup expectations on the mock. Someone more familiar with the Moq framework can help you with the code

Comment: you are creating a mock on the interface of the class you want to test. Why ? Then you are instantiating the ConsoleTargetBuilder but there is not method call in the constructor. What are you testing ? Your mock will never ever be called.

Comment: Are you trying to test code inside AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret or just the fact that AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret was called?

Comment: @sleepwalker, I want two things. A) the method was called. B) two targets were added. So the expected count is 2.

Comment: Nobody is going to call that method. You have to call it yourself, or change the constructor to call AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret();

Comment: As an aside, `AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret` seems like it should probably be named `AddNLogConfigurationTypeTarget`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you don't need a mock at all. You are testing AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret. Not the constructor.

```
[Theory]
[MemberData("ConsoleTargetBuilderTestData")]
public void ConsoleTargetBuilder_Should_Add_A_Console_Target(LoggerModel loggerModel, LoggingConfiguration nLogLoggingConfiguration, int expectedConsoleTargetCount)
{
    // ARRANGE
    var consoleTargetBuilder = new ConsoleTargetBuilder(loggerModel, nLogLoggingConfiguration);
    // ACT
    consoleTargetBuilder.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret();
    // ASSERT
    Assert.Equal(expectedConsoleTargetCount, nLogLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets.Count);
}
```

If you don't want to call AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret yourself, it should be called in the constructor. This changes the test to this :

```
[Theory]
[MemberData("ConsoleTargetBuilderTestData")]
public void ConsoleTargetBuilder_Should_Add_A_Console_Target(LoggerModel loggerModel, LoggingConfiguration nLogLoggingConfiguration, int expectedConsoleTargetCount)
{
    // ARRANGE
    // ACT
    var consoleTargetBuilder = new ConsoleTargetBuilder(loggerModel, nLogLoggingConfiguration);
    // ASSERT
    Assert.Equal(expectedConsoleTargetCount, nLogLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets.Count);
}
```

and the class constructor should then be :

```
public ConsoleTargetBuilder(LoggerModel loggerModel, LoggingConfiguration nLogLoggingConfiguration)
{
    _loggerModel = loggerModel;
    _nLogLoggingConfiguration = nLogLoggingConfiguration;
    AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret();
}
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Don't take this code as is. I am trying to give you assistance by giving example code and explanation. The point is you don't need to mock the interface the dut is implementing.

Comment: @Love You really need to say which line you're getting the object reference error from.  On the face of it, it could simply be that your loggerModel.layout returns null for example..

Answer (score 2):

> Please guide me to the right direction, I want two things. A) the method was called. B) two targets were added. So the expected count is 2.

**A)** If you wish to verify that method `AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret` was called, then you need to test it on the code which is calling this method. E.g. something like the class `ConsoleTargetBuilderClient` which is *an hypothetical example* of a class which is using the `ITargetBuilder` *(in your own code you should have some place where the class `ConsoleTargetBuilder` is used)*.

```
public class ConsoleTargetBuilderClient
{
    private ITargetBuilder _builder;

    public ConsoleTargetBuilderClient(ITargetBuilder builder)
    {
        _builder = builder;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _builder.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret();
    }
}
```

Then you can have a test which verifies that the method `DoSomething` called the method `AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret`. For that purpose you can use a mock of `ConsoleTargetBuilder` because you test interaction with it. Test might look like this:

```
    public void DoSomething_WhenCalled_AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagretGetsCalled()
    {
        // Arrange
        bool addNLogConfigurationTypeTagretWasCalled = false;
        Mock<ITargetBuilder> targetBuilderMock = new Mock<ITargetBuilder>();
        targetBuilderMock.Setup(b => b.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret())
            .Callback(() => addNLogConfigurationTypeTagretWasCalled = true);
        ConsoleTargetBuilderClient client = new ConsoleTargetBuilderClient(targetBuilderMock.Object);

        // Act
        client.DoSomething();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(addNLogConfigurationTypeTagretWasCalled);
    }
```

**B)** If you wish to verify that the targets were added you need to test the code itself (not mock of it). Test might look like this:

```
public void AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret_WhenCalled_ConsoleTargetsAdded()
{
    // Arrange
    const int expectedConsoleTargetCount = 2;
    var loggerModel = new LoggerModel();
    var nLogLoggingConfiguration = new LoggingConfiguration();
    var consoleTargetBuilder = new ConsoleTargetBuilder(loggerModel, nLogLoggingConfiguration);

    // Act
    consoleTargetBuilder.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual<int>(expectedConsoleTargetCount, nLogLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets.Count);
}
```

*Note: google value-based vs. state-based vs. interaction testing.*

Comment: I am going to use your code. Does `ConsoleTargetBuilderClient` have to inheritance the `ITargetBuilder` interface? As my code inheritance it...

Comment: ```ConsoleTargetBuilderClient``` is just a hypothetical example of a class which uses the ```ConsoleTargetBuilder```. In your own code you have to have some place where the ```ConsoleTargetBuilder``` is used and this code can be used like the ```ConsoleTargetBuilderClient```. So it does not inherit from the interface, it has an instance of class which implements it. HTH

Comment: Okay. How to implement `AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret` in the `ConsoleTargetBuilderClient` class? You have `_builder.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()` in the code but just one line. I mean details of this method.

Comment: ```AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret ``` is implemented in class ```ConsoleTargetBuilder : ITargetBuilder```. The client class just receives the builder in constructor and uses it. It is just an example of a class which is using the builder.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't be mocking the class you want to test, you should be mocking it's dependencies.  When you start mocking the class you're trying to test things often get entwined leading to brittle tests and it's difficult to determine if you're testing your code,  or you mocking setup, or both.

The method `AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret` is a public method on the class you're testing, so as @Philip has said, you should probably just be calling it from your test, or it should be called from your constructor.  If you goal is for it to be called from your constructor, then I'd suggest that it should probably be a private method unless there's a reason for it to be called from outside the class.

As far as testing the effects of a void method call, you're interested in the state change caused by the method.  In this instance, whether or not the `_nLoggingConfiguration` has two targets added with the correct attributes.  You don't show us the `nLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets` property, but I would assume from the fact that you're using the `Count` property in your test, that you could simply inspect the items in the list to confirm that the correct name and layout have been added to the correct target type.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assert
targetBuilderMock.Verify(x => x.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret(), Times.Once());
```

Comment: After adding your code, I got the following. Result Message: 
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()

Configured setups:
x => x.AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret(), Times.Never
No invocations performed.
Result StackTrace: 
at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1 setups, IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times, Int32 callCount)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)

Comment: Then your unit test is failing, and you need to make it pass. Are you sure that the `AddNLogConfigurationTypeTagret()` method is being called? Moq says it isn't.